# Failing to call subprocess - Python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, yolo

I would like to launch the darknet.exe command (YOLOv3) from a Py script because I am automating some stuff at work.

Here's the code (note: xxxxx in the folder name is just for privacy!):

```
cmdDarkent = r"C:\Users\YodhResearch\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\darknet.exe "
cmdDetector = "detector "
cmdTest = "test "
cmdData = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\data\obj\GoodTraining\obj.data "
cmdCfg = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\data\obj\GoodTraining\yolo-obj.cfg "
cmdWeights = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\data\obj\GoodTraining\yolo-obj_final.weights "
cmdImage = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\data\obj\GoodTraining\divertixxxxx\TreatR01-7_14-38_ROI1366-0461_ImageROI1_00n.PNG "
cmdExtOutput = r"-ext_output"

import subprocess
subprocess.call([cmdDarkent, cmdDetector, cmdTest, cmdData, cmdCfg, cmdWeights, cmdImage, cmdExtOutput],shell=True)
```

My output:

```
CUDA-version: 10020 (10020), cuDNN: 7.6.5, CUDNN_HALF=1, GPU count: 1
 OpenCV version: 3.4.9
Not an option: detector
```

It's starting the command but it doesn't find detector as option but I am 100% sure that this is the right way. Here's the full command:

```
darknet.exe detector test data\obj\GoodTraining\obj.data data\obj\GoodTraining\yolo-obj.cfg data\obj\GoodTraining\yolo-obj_final.weights C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\data\obj\GoodTraining\divertixxxxx\TreatR01-7_14-38_ROI1366-0461_ImageROI1_00n.PNG -ext_output
```

This is what I expect to see:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64>darknet.exe detector test data\obj\GoodTraining\obj.data data\obj\GoodTraining\yolo-obj.cfg data\obj\GoodTraining\yolo-obj_final.weights C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\darknet-master\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64\data\obj\GoodTraining\divertixxxxx\TreatR01-7_14-38_ROI1366-0461_ImageROI1_00n.PNG -ext_output
 CUDA-version: 10020 (10020), cuDNN: 7.6.5, CUDNN_HALF=1, GPU count: 1
 OpenCV version: 3.4.9
 compute_capability = 750, cudnn_half = 1
net.optimized_memory = 0
batch = 1, time_steps = 1, train = 0
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    416 x 416 x   3 ->  416 x 416 x  32 0.299 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    416 x 416 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
   2 conv     32       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  32 0.177 BF
   3 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    208 x 208 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
```

What am I missing?

I really hope this is not a doubled question but I don't find what I am looking for.

p.s.: The path are different in the python script just because the pyscript is in another directory than the "expected" command. In this case, it knows where to find it!

Comment: `cmdDetector = "detector "` Why do all your values have a trailing space?  I believe that is your issue.

Comment: Because I thought: "hey, do I need spaces or it does it automatically?" Well, I guessed wrong. LOL.... It works now, it can't open a file but its not a subprocess problem. Well, Thanks you very much!

Comment: When dealing with arrays, like you are doing, it will join them with a space in them.

Comment: The argument to `subprocess.call` can be a list, but you should then omit `shell=True`. The wrong combination happens to work on Windows, though.